# $a \sin(30^\circ) - b\sin(45^\circ)=1$, and $a\cos(30^\circ) +b\cos(45^\circ)=0$. Solve for $a$ and $b$.

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

> $a \sin(30^\circ) - b\sin(45^\circ)=1$, and $a\cos(30^\circ) +b\cos(45^\circ)=0$. Solve for $a$ and $b$.

Just trying to help my brother out in regards to this question but for the life of me I cant even figure out how to go about it, very simple question so apologies in advance, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Substitute the values of sine and cosine of angles. Then solve the $2$ linear equations in $A$ and $B%>

Comment: so it would become, 0.5a - 0.7b=1 and 0.87a + 0.7b= 0, right? and then i solve them like a simultaneous equation or is linear equations different lol, sorry its just been so long since i did a level maths

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: so far I've tried solving it like a simultaneous equation, reading through the replies now trying other users methods

Answer (score 1):

$a \dfrac {1}{2}-b\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=1$

$a\dfrac{\sqrt3}{2}+b\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=0$

By adding equations

$a=\sqrt{3}-1$

$b$ can be found by substituting $a$ in one of the equations

Comment: thank you for the response, i am a bit confused, where did the square root of 2 over 2 come from?

Comment: $\sin45=\cos45=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Comment: thank you for the help!

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

First find out what the values are for the consine and sine angles with degree but leave them as fractions not decimals.

Cos(30 degrees) = ✓3/2
Sin (30) = 1/2

Cos(45) = ✓2/2
and Sin(45) = ✓2/2

So, then: 1/2 * A -  ✓2/2 * B = 1
And also: ✓3/2 * A + ✓2/2 * B = 0

Now we have a system of equations. You can use substitution method or other method.

Adding vertically, the B terms cancel leaving us with: 2A = 1  and so A = 1/2

Then we take this result and plug into any of the two equations above: 1/2 * 1/2 - ✓2/2 * B = 1
Which gives: 1/4 - 1 = ✓2/2 * B
And then:  -3/4 = ✓2/2 * B
-3/4 * 2/✓2 = B
-3/2 * 1/✓2 = B
-3/2 * ✓2/ 2 = B
(-3✓2) / 4 = B

If I did this correctly, it should be that.

Comment: sorry, did it again, works perfectly. thank you !